# Media Queries Not Recognized by Gmail App

Tags: css, responsive-design, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to design a responsive e-mail but media queries are being ignored by the Gmail app. They are recognized elsewhere, such as the Outlook app. I know Gmail not recognizing media queries has been a problem for a while now. I'm hoping someone has a current solution to this. Otherwise, how does one design a responsive email these days??

These are the two simple media queries I am using:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
img.headshot {
    float: left;
    width: 165px;
    height: 165px;
    }
} 
    
    
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
.small {
    font-size: 14.4px;
    }
}
```

One of the solutions I saw online was to close the space between "width:" and "480".  That didn't work.

Comment: It looks as though media queries have limited support in gmail. https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%40media

Comment: I don't know how far along email styling has come, but generally emails are built using tables.

Comment: There's lots already in SO on this. Not sure if one particular answer is best, but please research the top few: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+responsive+email+in+gmail&ia=web